# Severe errors in solr configuration

Tags: solr

Suddenly my Solr server stop working and I am having this error. Please someone let me know what to do.

HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /solr/wksolr. Reason:

```
Severe errors in solr configuration.
```

Check your log files for more detailed information on what may be wrong.

If you want solr to continue after configuration errors, change:

false

in solr.xml

---

java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or 'solr/--h/conf/', cwd=/opt/wk-solr
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.openResource(SolrResourceLoader.java:273)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.openConfig(SolrResourceLoader.java:239)
    at org.apache.solr.core.Config.(Config.java:141)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig.(SolrConfig.java:138)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:455)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:335)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:219)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$Initializer.initialize(CoreContainer.java:161)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.init(SolrDispatchFilter.java:96)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:713)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1282)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:518)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:499)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:985)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:194)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:534)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:441)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.main(Main.java:119)
Powered by Jetty://

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your --h core doesn't exist OR it doesn't have the solrconfig.xml file. If you are not using this core, you should remove its name from solr.xml and resart your solr instance.

Answer (score 1):

You must include a solrconfig.xml in your solr/--h/conf/ path.

For more information, see http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrConfigXml